# How to resolve recursive references with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

In my Json I have a Config referenced by other Config, and I want to have them in Config Classes pointing to other Config Classes by reference.
Basically, I need to convert the Integer values, to the Config Class that belongs to it, and I guess it should be recursive and throw exception if any loop.

I'm using Json.NET, so I'm wondering if there is a better aproach rather than deserializing it manually. I've already messed with IReferenceResolver and CustomCreationConverter but I may not know to use it's potential, it throws error when trying to convert an INTEGER to one of my Config classes.

Sample:

```
{
    "Configs":
    {
        "AConfig":
        [
            {
                "BConfig": 0, # point to BConfig first element, the only one in this case
                "CConfig": 1  # point to CConfig second element
                # other attributes
            },
            {
                "BConfig": 0 
                # other attributes
            }
        ],
        "BConfig":
        [
            {
                # other attributes
            }
        ],
        "CConfig":
        [
            {
                "AConfig": 1 # point to AConfig second element
                # other attributes
            },
            {
                "BConfig": 0 # point to BConfig first element
                # other attributes
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Config classes (if not specified in Json, config attribute must be null)

```
public abstract class Config
{
}
public class AConfig : Config
{
     public BConfig Bconfig { get; set; }
     public CConfig Cconfig { get; set; }
     // other attributes
}
public class BConfig : Config
{
     // other attributes
}
public class CConfig : Config
{
     public AConfig Aconfig { get; set; }
     public BConfig Bconfig { get; set; }
     // other attributes
}
```

Comment: Can you change the format of your json? It must contain the `$id` and `$ref`. See [Preserving Object References](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I can not have two $ref properties in a row in json, then how to differentiate?

Comment: Json.NET's [`PreserveReferencesHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm) does not use the format in your question.  If I serialize your data model with `PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects`, the result can be seen here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NTDu2D.  In contract your format includes **forward references** in which a reference from `AConfig` points to an object later in the document.  Since Json.NET is a single-pass stream serializer, this is not supported.

Comment: @dbc Thank you for this clarification, it helped me out to understand the problem. 
I will deserialize it manually using recursion and creating instances when I reach the base case, is to say when the 'config' has no more 'config pointers' inside.